# counting deletions in remove_if (c++ STL)

Tags: c++, stl, remove-if

Is there any way to count the number of deletions made by the remove_if function in the STL?

Specifically I am passing forward and back iterators each to vectors of ints, and have a lambda as the third argument as a comparative value for remove_if to determine if the vector should be deleted based on values in the vector. I want to know if there is a way to know the number of vectors deleted by remove_if afterwards.

Also, as a side question: I declare these vectors dynamically, so I am not sure if calling remove_if on these is bad practice.

Comment: Use a lambda for the comparison and have it increment a counter every time it will return true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Count the of elements before remove_if, and after.

```
auto old_size = list.size();
auto new_end = std::remove_if(list.begin(), list.end(), ...);
auto new_size = std::distance(list.begin(), new_end);
auto deletions = old_size - new_size;
```

Comment: Using `std::distance` is correct, however "count the elements before and after remove_if" is imprecise, as `remove_if` doesn't change the number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Longer answer (though @kukac 's) is correct.

`remove` and (`remove_if`) do not actually *remove* elements from the vector; they merely shuffle them to the end, and return an iterator to the start of the "removed" elements.  To actually get rid of them, you call `erase`.  This is called the ["erase-remove idiom"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom), and there's lots of posts about that.

Like this (uncompiled code):

```
vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5}; // v.size() == 5
auto it = remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), is_odd);
// now v looks something like this: {2,4,5,1,3}
//   the v.size() is still == 5
//   and it "points to" '5'
v.erase(it, v.end()); // erase all the elements that were "removed"
// now v looks something like this: {2,4}
//   the v.size() is now == 2
```

Comment: @Antonio, you are incorrect.  `v.erase(v.end(), v.end())` is perfectly fine; it removes all the elements in the half open range `[v.end(), v.end())` - of which there are none.

Comment: You are right, I have deleted my wrong comment and cancelled my vote.